# Find all records by isDirty

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

How would I go about filtering all records that are dirty? I've come up with a `$.grep()` way, but is there a native ember method like `this.store.find('sublist', { isDirty : true })`?

What I currently have is:

```
findAllDirty: function(){
    var all = this.get('model.sublists.content')

    all = $.grep(all, function(a){
       return a.get('isDirty') == true
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filter` on the store would be what you're looking for

```
this.store.filter('sublist', function(record){
  return record.get('isDirty');
});
```

Comment: How would I go about looping through each item and deleting the record. I tried `all.forEach(function(item){ this.store.deleteRecord(item) })` but it doesn't seem to be working, because it's not an array?

Comment: that would work just fine, the problem is, it's a live collection, meaning it populates asynchronously as it finds records.